# cannot init mean.io app. "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, mean.io

I got weird message during initializing Mean.IO app

```
Cloning branch: master into destination folder: mySystem
git clone  --depth 1  -bmaster https://github.com/linnovate/mean.git "mySystem"
Cloning into 'mySystem'...


##############################################################
#
#   !!! MONGOOSE WARNING !!!
#
#   This is an UNSTABLE release of Mongoose.
#   Unstable releases are available for preview/testing only.
#   DO NOT run this in production.
#
##############################################################

    DB connection successful!

Please provide password so we can create your first admin user
prompt: password:
C:\Users\?곹깭\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mean-cli\node_modules\mongoose\n
ode_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\base.js:246
        throw message;
              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at processResults (C:\Users\?곹깭\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mean-cli\
node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\db.js:1581:31)
    at C:\Users\?곹깭\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mean-cli\node_modules\mon
goose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\db.js:1619:20
    at C:\Users\?곹깭\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mean-cli\node_modules\mon
goose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\db.js:1157:7
    at C:\Users\?곹깭\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mean-cli\node_modules\mon
goose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\db.js:1890:9
    at Server.Base._callHandler (C:\Users\?곹깭\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\mean-cli\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\base
.js:448:41)
```

cli shows "prompt:", but I can't enter password. somehow enter key is in stdin, so "prompt:" is ignored.

i updated npm and installed python 2.7.9 and node-gyp. I did everything in troubleshooting section but it won't help.

Comment: I had the same issue. Tried everything but no luck.

Comment: Is your problem solved?